# Javascript newbie question

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a jquery plugin to upload files, the plugin checks the file dimension and return back the appropriate error message. the error message i am displaying is with this code.

```
$('#divmsg6').append("<p class = 'red'>Incorrect file dimension, try again</p>");
```

now if the user keep on trying the error will keep on appending, that's what append is meant for. instead of appending i want my error code to be replaced every time it finds one. what is the js code for that?

Comment: Couldn't you just change the innerHTML of divmsg6 to whatever error message you have each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it would be better to hide/show error than, removing/adding the same thing.

html

```
<div id="divmsg6"><p class = 'red'>Incorrect file dimension, try again</p></div>
```

css

```
#divmsg6 p.red {
   display: none;
}
```

when error occurs, jQuery it like this,

```
$('#divmsg6 p.red').show(); // show error message.
```

then you might want to hide on some time.

```
$('#divmsg6 p.red').show(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
       $this.fadeOut(1500);
    },1500);
});
```

or any other variation of hiding it will do, just show it again when error occur.

## [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5xQ2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$('#divmsg6').html("<p class = 'red'>Incorrect file dimension, try again</p>");
```